# Debian: how to uninstall every packages related to a removed package?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, package-management

I am doing tests with ZFS on Debian Bullseye 11.1, but this question is very general.

In my example with ZFS, the installation is very easy: `apt-get  install  zfsutils-linux  zfs-zed  zfs-dkms`
This install a bunch of packages, among them are *linux-headers-xxx*, *gcc*, *cpp*, etc.

When I uninstall ZFS I do `apt-get  autoremove  --purge  zfsutils-linux  zfs-zed  zfs-dkms`
This remove some packages, but lots remain installed although not needed anymore.
Among the remaining packages are *linux-headers-xxx*, *gcc*, and *cpp*.

I can have the list of packages installed at a certain time (looking into /var/log/apt/history.log or /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list), but this is time consumming and error prone.

After ZFS uninstallation, when I do `apt-get  autoremove` I get nothing more to uninstall.

--> how can I list/delete the packages automatically installed and no longuer needed?

Comment: search `debian remove dependencies` ... here is one hit ... https://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/03/07/debian-cleanup-tip-6-remove-automatically-installed-packages/

Comment: What happens if you do `apt-get autoremove --purge` without any package names?

Comment: Look at `/var/log/apt/*` and you can see what got installed and when.

Comment: `/var/log/dpkg.log` is easier to parse and extract package names from than `/var/log/apt/history.log`.   See my answer to [Purged XDG from Raspbian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673775/7696) which explains the dpkg.log file format and has an example of using awk to of extract package names from it.