# How to reinstall packages that were accidentally deleted

Tags: apt, kali-linux, pulseaudio, libraries, desktop

So I was trying to fix my pulseaudio and I ran the following 2 commands

```
sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get -y autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/
```

Based on an answer some one else posted.
When I rebooted my system my desktop now no longer shows up. I think it's because the first command uninstalled some important libraries accidentally. Is there any way to find what I uninstalled and reinstall it, or any way to make sure the bare minimum libraries are installed?

I am using a kali linux environment inside WSL

Thanks

Comment: Extract the list of removed/purged packages from /var/log/dpkg.log.   e.g. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673634/purged-xdg-from-raspbian/673775

Comment: Look into `/var/log/apt/history.log`. You should find there a list of uninstalled packages.